# How to get back the old "menu" on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, menu

I am attempting to setup a new install with a fully updated Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I recall in previous versions of Ubuntu there was a specific menu ability, which started off some type of symbol in the upper left-hand corner (memory fails me to recall exactly what)

This menuing allowed one to access all of the programs, system tools etc., without the need for superfluous add-ons. The operating system did this "out of the box".

How does one restore that menu system?

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu desktop has changed a lot over time.

Now Ubuntu is using Unity, but you can use the [classic-menu indicator](https://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) to mimic the old gnome-shell behavior.

To install the latest version (0.11 for Trusty) open a terminal and execute the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

After installing, go to the classic menu Indicator (last entry in the image) and select **'use old icon'**.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I believe UbuntuStudio had this type of menu on all versions up to and including UbuntuStudio 20.04. However, I can't speak for newer versions of UbuntuStudio like 22.04 because UbuntuStudio switched to KDE and I haven't tried the new desktop yet.

On UbuntuStudio 20.04 and older, they use a customized version of the XFCE4 desktop environment. Xubuntu and the XFCE desktop should give you a similar desktop setup and many users switched to XFCE when Gnome Shell was released. Therefore, Xubuntu or the XFCE desktop could be an option if you feel UbuntuStudio is too bloated and doesn't fit your needs (UbuntuStudio often includes either a suite of graphics software and/or audio software).

Also, Kubuntu and KDE use a basic menu setup but it may seem unfamiliar to you if you're used to GTK software. However, you might want to give it a try. Again, many users switched to KDE when Gnome Shell was released.

Other options like Ubuntu Mate and Lubuntu offer a similar, more familiar desktop experience compared to Gnome Shell. Although again, Lubuntu uses QT instead of GTK.

[There is a brief overview of all Ubuntu flavors on the Ubuntu website.](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours)